# Scripted Office uninstall help needed

Tags: batch-file, ms-office, uninstallation

I am trying to script the uninstallation of some MS Office programs, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to find the ProductID code I will need to add to the xml file?  I know that for Standard it is "standard" and for ProPlus it is "ProPlusR", but I also need to uninstall Home Business 2013 (might be Small Business 2013?), and I can't figure out what the ProductID needs to be.  I have queried an installed version of it with powershell, but the "ProductID" property is always blank, so that doesn't help either.

So far, I have tried the following without success: HomeBus, HomeBusR, SmBus, SmBusR, Business, HomeBusiness, SmallBusiness, HomeBusinessRetail, SmallBusinessRetail.

The answer I would prefer, is how I can find this info myself, as I will likely have additional versions I need to script, but I appreciate whatever help anyone can provide.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The uninstall command line of an installed application is recorded in Windows registry under the keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

The second key exists only on 64-bit Windows and is for 32-bit applications the same key as the first one, see [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

The applications (products) installed with Microsoft Installer (MSI) are registered with their unique identifiers under registry key :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I looked up the UninstallString on my test PC and tried it, but the string doesn't seem to work from a batch file.  It will only work from an administrative command prompt, which is somewhat expected, but it also does not work from a batch file ran as an admin.

Would I need to modify the uninstall string to run it from a batch file?  I would also rather have it run zero-touch (progress bar only with no user input, vs fully silent).  It is currently running fully interactively, which I'm sure is default.  Do you have any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Read for example [Setup command-line options reference for Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178956.aspx) for information about silent uninstall of Office. And run `msiexec /?` to get displayed a GUI window with the general options supported by __msiexec__ like `/quiet`. The uninstall must be of course executed with administrative privileges. In a batch file you have to wait for each uninstall to be completed before running the next uninstall. So you have to use `start "Uninstall X" /wait %SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe ...`.